# Is it possible to create a catch-all email using postfix which accepts any email address and sends an email to an external address?

Tags: linux, email, magento, postfix-mta

Some background and my challenge:

**Background**

I am using Magento 2.x using a virtual machine set-up which runs on Ubuntu 16.04

**Challenge**

My goal is to be able to test emails sent to me from the Magento application.  In an ideal situation, I would not use an extension or third-party service (although a third-party SMTP server on the linux box could work).

To achieve my goal, I need to be able to register as a customer in the Magento application with *any* email address (fake or real) and have the email sent to the same external email address, no matter what.

**What I've done so far**

1. I've installed postfix
2. I've installed Magento using `luma.com` as the domain (and set up my hosts file accordingly on my host machine, etc.)
3. I've created a linux user account called "contact"
4. I've configured `inet_interfaces` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` as `loopback-only`
5. I've set `mydestination` to `$myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain`
6. I've configured Magento to send its store emails from `contact@luma.com`
7. I've set up an aliases file as the following:

   ```
   postmaster:    root
   root:          contact
   contact:       me@gmail.com
   ```

Then I ran `newaliases` As far as I recall, email sends fine with this setup.  Hooray!

Next, the catch-all part.  For this, I've tried loads of things, and none seem to work.  From the reading I've done, I've tried the following:

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, I added the following:

```
    virtual_alias_domains = luma.com
    virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Next, in `/etc/postfix/virtual`, I encountered my first problem.  As far as I understand from the reading I've done, I'm supposed to use something like:

```
    @example.com   contact
```

This step apparently ensures that any email sent via postfix (e.g. from the Magento application) which uses an `@example.com` email address would be routed to the `contact` linux user I created above.  Then, my thinking was that the system would use the alias I set up to ultimately send out that email from `contact@luma.com` (via the settings in Magento) through to the external address I set up in the aliases file.  This approach would theoretically allow a user to register for an account with Magento using, say, `joe@example.com`, and then send the associated Welcome email to my external email address.

The issue with this is that I need the system to do this for *any* email, not just for emails ending in `@example.com`

Just for sake of completeness, I'll say that before asking this question, I was most recently researching how to achieve this part of the challenge using pcre tables. I've also tried configuring something using `luser_relay`, but both of these things are over my head at this point, so I'm lost.

My hope is that someone can offer some guidance as to whether I'm on the right path, where I may have missed something, and ultimately, offer some advice on whether my challenge can be solved and how I might go about solving it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Very well written question, unfortunately off-topic here. Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not mail server or linux generic stuff; I suggest you move this to https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ ...  I have voted to close it as off-topic.

Comment: You should look into postfixadmin.  It's a mysql backend for postfix and can easily help you achieve your goal.